# JasperReports: Error creating table trying to use CrossTab without column group

Tags: java, jasper-reports, crosstab

I'm wondering if there is a way to make a table like this [image] using the `JapserReports CrossTab` or **in any other way** where the row group is the field `value7`.

The DataSet used is a `JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list of SubViews)`.

Where SubView is:

```
public class SubView{

  //...

  private String value1;
  private String value2;
  private String value3;
  private String value4;
  private String value5;
  private String value6;
  private String value7;

  //...getters and setters...
}
```

Note that there is no need of a column group, but jasper doesn't compile successfully if I don't configure a column group (error message: `Crosstab should have at least one column group`).

Comment: I have edit your question so it can be useful for other, hence we have not used crosstabs....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This to me does not seem like a `crosstab` problem. `Crosstab`'s are used when the columns are **dynamic**, hence your error message

> Crosstab should have at least one column group.

since there is *"no need of a column group"*  the result is achived using the normal `detail band` and `grouping` on `value7`.

So after you put the labels in the `columnHeader` and the values 1-6 in the `detail band` you add a grouping on value7 with a `groupHeader` band

Example (I have only included until value 3 in `detail band` to sorten the answer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report2" printOrder="Horizontal" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isFloatColumnFooter="true" uuid="8944f542-2955-4224-933c-5a87fd36f527">
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>
<field name="value1" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="value2" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="value3" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="value7" class="java.lang.String"/>
<group name="Value7">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{value7}]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="21">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="300" height="20" uuid="208ca6e5-b396-47cb-858b-71039f5bdf7a"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Value 7: " + $F{value7}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
</group>
<background>
    <band/>
</background>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="50">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="100" height="20" uuid="edf0f0f1-c979-4d20-987e-e8decb0b584a"/>
            <text><![CDATA[value1]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="100" y="30" width="100" height="20" uuid="4287323f-e6d3-40d8-a2d4-44981bfa5c59"/>
            <text><![CDATA[value2]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="200" y="30" width="100" height="20" uuid="b9aa7dfd-edd8-439b-b4c7-12916a740da8"/>
            <text><![CDATA[value3]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="24">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="2bcc436d-4c3a-4db1-a2ea-87edf92af98f"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value1}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="f893721e-1aa6-44ca-9a9a-ac795ff63a0a"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value2}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="36ad9612-620b-4eec-9608-f26b5306b01a"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value3}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
</jasperReport>
```

If you like to use crosstab anyway, you need to setup your dataset differently (since also columns become dynamic) check out this for examples: [crosstab example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_crosstabs.htm)

Comment: I should put your code example inside `<jr:table></jr:table>` right ?

Comment: I'm using Jaspersoft Studio version 6.1.1.final (eclipse plugin)

Comment: I use IReport or directly edit .jrxml file, so I can't help you with JasperSoft Studio. My answer is related to standard jasper .jrxml files, I guess your Jaspersoft Studio will create one as well, do you see a .jrxml file, have you tired to open it?

Comment: Of course I did open it
It seems like in the last version, they have changed the XSD so that when I try your code I got an error. Table with version 6.1.1.final are represented in .jrxml file like below :
`<componentElement>
<reportElement>
<property />
</reportElement>
<jr:table >
<jr:column >
<property/>
<jr:columnHeader >
<staticText>
<reportElement />
<text></text>
</staticText>
</jr:columnHeader>
<jr:detailCell>
<textField>
<reportElement />
<textFieldExpression></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
</jr:detailCell>
</jr:column>
</jr:table>
</componentElement>`

Comment: Ok you are using a jasper component jr:table, in my example this was not used. I will edit answer so that you can see whole jrxml file

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: any version from jasper report from 1,3 --> 6.0, the file that I have provided is a .jrxml file and it wil compile to .jasper on any version of jasper report. (if very old maybe better to remove uuid), You can open it with iReport. I have no experience with JasperSoft Studio but I would be surprised if you can't open it.

Comment: NOTE: I'm not using the jr:table component!!, but doing the old fasion way.. and it will compile also on latest jasper report lib.

Comment: I managed to make your code works even with version 6.1.1.final (I created a file using iReport version 5 then I opened it with Jaspersoft Studio). But  my last question is how did you define a dataset to your code, or should I use it as subreport and define a dataset for it ?

Comment: since you wan't the JRBeanCollectionDataSource I created one and passed on to the fill metod. JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(sourceFileName, parameters, datasource);, if you do not need subreport its enough to pass it in the fillManager..

Comment: Thank you everything is ok now !